# How Do I Transfer Environment Variables with a Parallel-SSH Library

Tags: python, iot

I'm connecting to a SSH enable IoT device using the parallel-ssh library. The devices changes its behavior if an environment variable is present or not.

This device has a very limited, proprietary shell. I cannot set the variable by sending an export PERSONA=BOB command to it. I can test it with Putty by setting the environment in the GUI:

[SEE IMAGE (MIGHT HELP)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvbS5.png)

How can I set an environment variable on my parallel-ssh connexion?

Comment: what happens when you send the `export PERSONA=BOB` command?

Comment: I cant, the device has a very rubbish shell

Comment: So how does this mean you can’t send the command?

Comment: Because it doesn't allow it